# search text in url using mechanize python

Tags: python, regex, mechanize

*Hello I need to check if some text like 'good' is in a url page.I am using mechanize I saw some response in this site and others but no one works for me.
I saw '''.body.include?()''' but that doesnt work for me please help me
i know the website says godd new when the check is ok so i tried this*

```
if "Good news" in isitwp_response:
    rowdict['iswordpresswebsite'] = "yes"
else:
    rowdict['iswordpresswebsite'] = "no
```

but that doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the info. Try `bs4` with the `BeautifulSoup` class.
Firstly, the response itself does not tell you anything. Try `isitwp_response.read()` for the actual information from the site.

Feed the soup

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(isitwp_response.read(),'html.parser')
```

the `find()` function will return the text you're searching for if it's there. (tried and tested on another site)

```
if soup.find(text='Good news')==None:
    return(False)
else:
    return(True)
```